# How can I parse a gzipped file in Python and later append to it, even if doesn't exist?

Tags: python, file, file-io, gzip, fopen

Let's say that you have a file which contains several values, one per line. You want to open that file, parse those values, do some processing, and later append new values to that file. If the file doesn't exist, then it should be created and, after the processing, the lines appended.

The normal way to do it would be something like this:

```
with open(path, 'a+') as data:
  for line in file:
    values.update(line.strip())

  for line in magic_processing():
    print(line, file = data)
```

However, doing this using `gzip.open` instead of `open` fails with the following message:

```
AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'extrastart'
```

This seems to be [because of this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue18323), which this leads me to believe that there must be a nicer or standard-er way to do this.

Answer (score -2):

When you use `open(file, 'a+')` with `a+` mode that mean that you will append to it, while:

> - `a+` Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist. The initial file position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but output is appended to the end of the file (but in some Unix systems regardless of the current seek position).

But you tried to update lines that could be in the middle of the file. So what I would suggest is to use `r+` or `w+` instead

```py
with open(path, 'r+') as data:
  for line in file:
    values.update(line.strip())

  for line in magic_processing():
    print(line, file = data)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and your code doesn't use `gzip.open`.
The problem here is that due to an implementation detail, `gzip.open` doesn't let you open files with `r+`, `w+`, or `a+`, and fails with an uninformative message.